# Adding a click handler to a panel?

Tags: gwt

We have the interface:

```
AbsolutePanel ap = ...;
ap.addHandler(EventHandler h, Type<EventHandler> type);
```

How do we use the above? It seems like the interface for click events has changed a few times in GWT, and older questions on this topic are out of date,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
    AbsolutePanel ap = new AbsolutePanel();
    ap.addHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```